# What is the purpose of the <nav> tag

Tags: html, navigation

I have read a whole bunch of questions regarding where and how nav tags should be used and 
I get that we are meant to put "major" navigational elements within it but what is it's purpose?

I can see that [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp) says that

> "Browsers, such as screen readers for disabled users, can use this
>   element to determine whether to omit the initial rendering of this
>   content."

but does it have any further use, are there any other implications of omitting the `<nav>` tag?

Comment: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use. I recommend using the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.

Comment: Implications? Such as?

Comment: Googling "html5 nav tag purpose" gave a good answer - [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a semantic improvement in HTML. A random section of the page with

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
...
```

doesn't mean much in and of itself, and is only understood as being a "navigational" component when viewed by a user on the graphical page. Someone who is using a screen reader, or a text browser, or any kind of assistive technology would not know be easily able to understand the meaning behind the tag soup.

On the other hand, by enclosing your markup in *meaningful*, semantic tags, it would be very easy for a screen reader to understand that a specific part of the document is meant to be used as a nav, and take the necessary action.

In addition, it's also easier for a developer to look at the markup and immediately recognize what it is for.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
...
```

Comment: I fail to see the need of ul/li. It only requires additional styling `list-style: none; padding-left: 0;`

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of tags like `<nav>` is semantic markup: i.e. understand-ability and sensible descriptions of page elements. The alternative of `<div id='nav'>` is OK but much more clunky. Web crawlers and the like are much happier to find your content well described and laid out so I would recommend making use of tags like this as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Tools/user-agents may (or may not) do *anything* with it; now or in the future.

You do your job (marking up your content), tools do their job (interpreting your markup). The only "implication of omitting" the `nav` element is, well, that these tools can’t use this information for their interpretation.

The [`nav` definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) gives a non-normative note:

> User agents (such as screen readers) that are targeted at users who can benefit from navigation information being omitted in the initial rendering, or who can benefit from navigation information being immediately available, can use this element as a way to determine what content on the page to initially skip or provide on request (or both).

But it’s not hard to imagine other purposes:

- text browsers may display the navigation differently
- mobile browsers may offer a way to display/hide the navigation
- search engines may ignore navigation content for ranking the page
- printers may exclude the navigation by default
- …

The more about the page structure is known, the more can be done with the page by various tools. It’s the whole point of the so-called *semantic markup*.